Why is unpacking a list in indexing a syntax error in Python 3.8 but not Python 3.12?
The following code
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(32).reshape(2,2,2,2,2)
extra = [1 for _ in range(3)]
print(x[*extra, 0, 0])

prints 28 as expected in Python 3.12 but results in the syntax error
  File "main.py", line 4
    print(x[*extra, 0, 0])
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

in Python 3.8.
Replacing the indexing with print(x[(*extra, 0, 0)]) works in both versions.
The NumPy documentation states that the offending line is syntax sugar for the working one, so I do not understand why there is a syntax error.
A quick search for the terms "unpack","index", and "getitem" for the versions 3.9 to 3.12 (inclusive) on https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/index.html didn't turn up any indication that there was a change to indexing or unpacking syntax, although I may have missed something. The closest I found was that Python 3.11 has the change "Starred unpacking expressions can now be used in for statements."

oh, gosh, I do remember that there was something related to this, probably after the new PEG parser came out. I can't find it though

Unpacking wasn't allowed without paren's until 3.9, but not fully supported until 3.11. If you look through some of the cpython git issues you can track it down if you are really interested. Features/functionality change regularly betwen version so I'm not certain why/what you are asking. [https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90881, https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/2321]. You can start your trace under the "Other Lang Changes" ref: bpo-46725: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html

@scrappedcola I suppose a more precise version of my question would be "where is this change documented?" I will take a look at the links.

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90881 seems like this may have snuck in with the PEG parser and it retroactively became a feature :)

Also interesting, from an issue in the Ruff linter github: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/2321

This was a consequence of grammar changes in PEP 646 – Variadic Generics and somehow didn't get a mention in the changelog for 3.11.
Minimal reproducer:
$ python3.11 -c 'print({():42}[*()])'
42
$ python3.10 -c 'print({():42}[*()])'
  File "<string>", line 1
    print({():42}[*()])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

The relevant diff can be found at #31018: Implement PEP 646 grammar changes.

ahhhhh that was it! I knew this was specifically mentioned in some PEP

I knew I saw this before!
